# how to a send friend request while the user table and the friends table are in relation in php using yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a user table with the user details and a friends table with userid(FK),friendid,and status(enum->SEND,ACCEPT,BLOCK) now i need to search for the friend by entering the friends name and after that i need to send request that friend and after sending the request to the friend when he logged in to his account there must be a notification about the friend request...

Comment: And which part of that process are you asking about?Also , don't use enum for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have another database design proposition:

```
Table: FriendRequest 
Fields: frID->Id 
        frSendBy->Id of the sender (in relation with User Table) 
        frSendTo -> Id of the receiver (in relation with User Table) 
        frIsViewed -> 1 or 0 if the request is viewed or not 
        frAccepted -> 1 or 0 if the request is accepted or refused
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same DB design, I created a table name "Notification" with following fields.

1. Noification_Id (int AI)
2. Sender_ID (int)
3. Receiver_ID (int)
4. Message(String)
5. read_status(int)
6. Status

Once you will send request it will insert notification to this table and after that when other user will login you need fetch notification check user_id with receiver_id and read_status. Once user accepted friend request you need to update notification table as well as friends table.